# Problem to get payment details with PayPal

Tags: php, api, paypal, transactions, payment

I use a PayPal smart button and I need to get the payment details after user make payment.

For example i need to get details so as below:

```
{
  "id": "5O190127TN364715T",
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "payer": {
    "name": {
      "given_name": "John",
      "surname": "Doe"
    },
    "email_address": "customer@example.com",
    "payer_id": "QYR5Z8XDVJNXQ"
  },
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "reference_id": "d9f80740-38f0-11e8-b467-0ed5f89f718b",
      "shipping": {
        "address": {
          "address_line_1": "2211 N First Street",
          "address_line_2": "Building 17",
          "admin_area_2": "San Jose",
          "admin_area_1": "CA",
          "postal_code": "95131",
          "country_code": "US"
        }
      },
      "payments": {
        "authorizations": [
          {
            "id": "0AW2184448108334S",
            "status": "CREATED",
            "amount": {
              "currency_code": "USD",
              "value": "100.00"
            },
            "seller_protection": {
              "status": "ELIGIBLE",
              "dispute_categories": [
                "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED",
                "UNAUTHORIZED_TRANSACTION"
              ]
            },
            "expiration_time": "2018-05-01T21:20:49Z",
            "create_time": "2018-04-01T21:20:49Z",
            "update_time": "2018-04-01T21:20:49Z",
            "links": [
              {
                "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v2/payments/authorizations/0AW2184448108334S",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v2/payments/authorizations/0AW2184448108334S/capture",
                "rel": "capture",
                "method": "POST"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v2/payments/authorizations/0AW2184448108334S/void",
                "rel": "void",
                "method": "POST"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v2/payments/authorizations/0AW2184448108334S/reauthorize",
                "rel": "reauthorize",
                "method": "POST"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/5O190127TN364715T",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to use in file for webhook:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
```

and  got a some info, which haven't amount, client account and etc. Could someone tell, how to do it with one php script without installing the api or tell me how to deploy api on my  server, so as the documentation is not enough to understand it how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The most robust solution would be to integrate SPB using the server-side front end UI: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

This will call two corresponding routes on your server, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

This way, you will receive the 'Capture Transaction' response with full details directly on your server, at the moment the transaction is made.  There will be no need for any asynchronous webhooks.